# How to sort on number of visits in Django app?

Tags: python, django

In Django (1.0.2), I have 2 models: Lesson and StatLesson.

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    contents = models.TextField()
    def get_visits(self):
        return self.statlesson_set.all().count()

class StatLesson(models.Model):
    lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lesson)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Each StatLesson registers 1 visit of a certain Lesson. I can use lesson.get_visits() to get the number of visits for that lesson.

How do I get a queryset of lessons, that's sorted by the number of visits? I'm looking for something like this: Lesson.objects.all().order_by('statlesson__count') (but this obviously doesn't work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django 1.1 will have aggregate support.

On Django 1.0.x you can count automatically with an extra field:

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    contents = models.TextField()
    visit_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class StatLesson(models.Model):
    lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lesson)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk is None:
            self.lesson.visit_count += 1
            self.lesson.save()
        super(StatLesson, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then you can query like this:

```
Lesson.objects.all().order_by('visit_count')
```

Comment: You mean you can't _natively_ in Django till 1.1 (when aggregate support arrives) - it is still possible in 1.0, just not as tidy.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do some native SQL stuff using [extra](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra-select-none-where-none-params-none-tables-none-order-by-none-select-params-none).

e.g. (very roughly)

```
Lesson.objects.extra(select={'visit_count': "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM statlesson WHERE statlesson.lesson_id=lesson.id"}).order_by('visit_count')
```

You'll need to make sure that `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM statlesson WHERE statlesson.lesson_id=lesson.id` has the write db table names for your project (as statlesson and lesson won't be right).